# Hbase 1.0.0 connection pool

Tags: java, multithreading, hbase

Since Hbase 1.0+ API is not handling the connection pooling using [`HConnection`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HConnection.html), I want to know what are the best practices for creating a connection pool?

So far, I have created a [`Connection`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html) object as [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), but I am not sure if it is good idea.

In general, since the connection object is so heavy, is it a good idea to create a pool of connections?

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked the question from [Carter Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309596/carter-page), and here is his answer:

"You don't have to use only one Connection per application, and in some certain cases you may discover a need for more than one.

In general, the important thing to know is that Connections are "heavy" objects that are expensive to create, but thread-safe. Table, Admin, and BufferedMutatator objects are lightweight and not necessarily thread-safe. 
Connection objects don't necessarily translate to a single "connection", and can multiplex behind the scenes. Better to think of it as a factory.

I would suggest you create a single Connection where possible, and carefully test increasing a pool if you think more factories will improve performance. There are certainly no rules against having more Connection objects. It's just a matter of potentially unnecessary overhead.  Hope this helps."

Answer (score 3):

You can use one connection per application because creating it is heavy and it is `thread-safe`. Make sure however that you close `Table` and `Admin` that you get from the `Connection`

```
private static class ConnectionHolder{
  private final Connection connection;

  private ConnectionHolder(){
   connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config); 
  }

 Connection getConnection(){
  return connection;
  }
}
```

If you use this approach don't expose `connection` so callers don't close it accidentally. But do remember to close `Tables` and `ResultScanners`

```
Table getTable(String name){
  Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(name));
  return table;
}

try(Table table = getTable("tableName")){
  ...
}
```

Comment: So, you suggest to keep one Connection object for the whole application, and not use a connection pool? is it right?

Comment: yes, thats a result of a long conversation on HBase mailing list :)

Comment: Do you have a link to that long conversation :)?

Comment: Tried hard but didn't find it, sorry

Comment: The thing is with multiple connection objects, I am getting better performance (obviously with the penalty of using more resources). That's why I want to know if there is a problem about using a pool?

Comment: I am little confused this with JDBC connection. Will multi request be blocked when  single connection used?